# partial template specialization for non type member function pointer values

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to partially specialize a structure for a non-type template parameter, specifically for member function pointers known at compile time.
As an example, I start with `int` and non `int` values and that works fine and prints

```
false true
```

but when I un-comment `adap`, I get the following compile error

```
callable.cc:9:39: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    9 | struct adap<Ret(Class::*Fptr)(Args...)> : std::false_type {};
```

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* Comment out
template <auto T>
struct adap : std::true_type {};

template <typename Ret, typename Class, typename ...Args>
struct adap<Ret(Class::*Fptr)(Args...)> : std::false_type {};
*/

template <auto T>
struct A {
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <int N>
struct A<N> {
   static constexpr bool value = false;
};

struct B {
   void f() {
   }
};

int main() {
   std::cout << boolalpha << A<4>::value << " " << A<char{'a'}>::value << endl;
//   adap<&B::f> ad;
}
```

Comment: What is `Fptr` intended to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a partial specialization for a template, you have to provide template argument(s) to the primary specialization that signal when your partial specialization should be used. The primary template for `adap` takes a non-type template parameter: a value. So your partial specialization needs to provide a value.

Which it doesn't. `Fptr` is not a value. I'm guessing that you intend it to be the name of a parameter. But you're not providing a parameter; you're providing an *argument*, one that fits the corresponding template parameter defined in the primary template. That parameter being an NTTP, you must provide a *value*. The idea being that when a user provides that value, your specialization will take over.

`auto`-deduced NTTP parameters were added so that you could avoid having to do something like this: `template<typename T, T value>`. Your specialization needs to basically bring this back. Your template header should take the component types of a member pointer (return type, class type, and arguments) *and* an NTTP value which is a member pointer type that uses these components. You then pass that value to the primary template:

```
template <auto T>
struct adap : std::true_type {};

template <typename Ret, typename Class, typename ...Args, Ret(Class::*value)(Args...)>
struct adap<value> : std::false_type {};
```

Comment: Hi @Nicol Bolas I have been searching alot on SO to find how to extend your answer to add a partial specialization for the case where the member function is const. Do you know how to do this? I have asked a separated question on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70920523/. If you wouldn't mind looking at it?