# How to partially specialize NTTP class template for const and non-const member function pointer

Tags: c++, c++20

Inspired by the section at the bottom of the page `template <auto>` [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html)

I have been trying to figure out how to make it work when the function is part of an overload set for example 2 functions a const and a non-const. I tried several things the struct Bar and Bar2 are 2 that I think should work but I am doing something wrong.

[Reference Code](https://godbolt.org/z/Pcz6d7d9s)

```
class TestStruct {
public:
    constexpr static int m_staticValue = 42;
    uint8_t m_value = m_staticValue;

    void somefunction(int& value)
    {
        std::cout << "somefunction " << value << "\n";
    }
    void somefunction(int& value) const
    {
        std::cout << "somefunction const " << value + 1 << "\n";
    }

};

template <typename T>
struct Foo;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Foo<Ret(Args...)> {

    template <auto>
    struct Bar: std::false_type
    {};
    
    template <typename Instance_T>
    using MemberFunction_Ptr = void(std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>::*)(int&);
    template <typename Instance_T>
    using MemberFunctionConst_Ptr = void(std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>::*)(int&) const;
    template <typename Instance_T>
    using MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<Instance_T>>, MemberFunctionConst_Ptr<Instance_T>, MemberFunction_Ptr<Instance_T>>;
    
    template <typename T, MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr<T> MF>
    struct Bar<MF> : std::true_type {
        template <typename U>
        Bar(U&& instance)
        {
        }
    };
    
    template <auto>
    struct Bar2: std::false_type
    {};
    
    template <typename T, void (T::*MF)(int&)>
    struct Bar2<MF> : std::true_type {
        template <typename U>
        Bar2(U&& instance)
        {
        }
    };
    
    template <typename T, void (T::*MF)(int&) const>
    requires std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
    struct Bar2<MF> {
        template <typename U>
        Bar2(const U&& instance)
        {
        }
    };

};


int main()
{
    auto test = std::mem_fn<void(int&)>(&TestStruct::somefunction);
    auto testConst = std::mem_fn<void(int&)const>(&TestStruct::somefunction);
    int value = 42;
    double valueDouble = 42;
    TestStruct testStruct;


    auto a = Foo<void(int&)>::Bar<&TestStruct::somefunction> { testStruct };
    auto b = Foo<void(int&)>::Bar2<&TestStruct::somefunction> { testStruct };
    return 0;
}
```

This `auto a = Foo<void(int&)>::Bar<&TestStruct::somefunction> { testStruct };` gives this **error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used**

and the second `auto b = Foo<void(int&)>::Bar2<&TestStruct::somefunction> { testStruct };`gives this **error: non-type template parameter '' with type 'auto' has incompatible initializer of type ''**

And I don't know how to fix any of those. I am maybe not approaching the problem from the right angle. But I feel like if we can specialize partially NTTP for member function pointer we should be able to have 2 specializations one for const and the other for non const. No?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't explicitly specify its type before `&TestStruct::somefunction`, so the compiler has no way of knowing whether you chose a const or non-const member function.

Comment: Yes but if I write it like this ` template <typename Instance_T, MemberFunctionConstOrNot_Ptr<Instance_T> fct> static void Bind(T &&instance)` and call it this way I don't have to cast it `Bind<TestStruct, &TestStruct::somefunction>Bind(testStruct);` Because the constness is deduced by the function paramter. I was trying to do the same.